# ERROR: gcloud crashed (EOFError): EOF when reading a line

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have installed the GCP SDK on a virtualbox vm and trying to test the commands. I get the following error:

```
Enter the output of the above command: ERROR: gcloud crashed (EOFError): EOF when reading a line
```

when I run the command:

```
sudo docker run -ti --name gcloud-config gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli gcloud auth login --no-browser
```

but these commands work:

```
sudo docker run -ti --name gcloud-config gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli gcloud version
sudo docker run -ti --name gcloud-config gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> --no-browser
>
> If you want to authorize the gcloud CLI on a machine that doesn't have a browser and you can install the gcloud CLI on another
> machine with a browser, use the --no-browser flag.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login

Try this: `gcloud auth login --no-browser`

Comment: I did and same error